# Sample create powerpoint with openxml

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

Where can I find the 'Hello World' with the insert text and image in a ppt file with OpenXML? I'm not able to generate a simple template.

Answer (score 4):

Before going to develop a template for PowerPoint, read the presentationML structure from this [PDF](http://openxmldeveloper.org/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-00-00-19-70/Open-XML-Explained.pdf),

Refer the follwing link for creating PPT using OPENXML.
[How to: Create a presentation document by providing a file name (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278317.aspx)

Refer following link for insert image into the PPT
[Insert image into the PPT File.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee412267.aspx)

For Further Examples in OpenXML Refer: **[OPENXML Developerorg](http://openxmldeveloper.org/)**

Comment: OPENXML content is being moved to [Eric White's blog](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/)

Comment: Does C# 2.0 support Open XML SDK ?

Comment: You can use lower version of OpenXML SDK.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/1.0.0