# PowerPoint REST API?

Tags: rest, api, powerpoint

I'm looking for a **REST API for generating PowerPoint slides**... does anyone have any suggestions?

Realize this wouldn't be too difficult to implement, but we're trying to avoid building noncore functionality we could get from a third party.

Basically, we want to send a JSON blob and get back the generated slide.

Think this is a **related question**:
[Is there an API to make a MS Office 365 Powerpoint presentation programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948593/is-there-an-api-to-make-a-ms-office-365-powerpoint-presentation-programmatically)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would really appreciate some help. Any advice or resources you can share?

Comment: @RudyOnRails - did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Rest powerpoint api here: https://api-pptxbuilder.herokuapp.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Aspose.Slides Cloud](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/) for your purposes. This product provides REST-based APIs for many programming languages (C#, Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, Node.js, C++, Go, Perl, Swift), platforms and environments. With this product, you can use both Aspose file storages and third-party storages. Docker containers can also be used for working with Aspose.Slides Cloud.

This product does not support adding contents to presentations from JSON files but it provides many features for generating contents. It also provides features to add contents to presentations from HTML and PDF documents. The following Python sample code shows you how to add a WordArt object to a new presentation, for example.

```py
import asposeslidescloud

from asposeslidescloud.apis.slides_api import SlidesApi
from asposeslidescloud.models.slide_export_format import SlideExportFormat
from asposeslidescloud.models.shape import Shape
from asposeslidescloud.models.fill_format import FillFormat
from asposeslidescloud.models.line_format import LineFormat
from asposeslidescloud.models.text_frame_format import TextFrameFormat
from asposeslidescloud.models.three_d_format import ThreeDFormat
from asposeslidescloud.models.shape_bevel import ShapeBevel
from asposeslidescloud.models.light_rig import LightRig
from asposeslidescloud.models.camera import Camera

slides_api = SlidesApi(None, "my_client_id", "my_client_secret")

file_name = "example.pptx"
slide_index = 1

dto = Shape()
dto.shape_type = "Rectangle"
dto.x = 100
dto.y = 100
dto.height = 100
dto.width = 200
dto.text = "Sample text"

dto.fill_format = FillFormat()
dto.fill_format.type = "NoFill"

dto.line_format = LineFormat()
dto.line_format.fill_format = FillFormat()
dto.line_format.fill_format.type = "NoFill"

text_frame_format = TextFrameFormat()
text_frame_format.transform = "ArchUpPour"

three_d_format = ThreeDFormat()
bevel_bottom = ShapeBevel()
bevel_bottom.bevel_type = "Circle"
bevel_bottom.height = 3.5
bevel_bottom.width = 3.5
three_d_format.bevel_bottom = bevel_bottom

bevel_top = ShapeBevel()
bevel_top.bevel_type = "Circle"
bevel_top.height = 4
bevel_top.width = 4
three_d_format.bevel_top = bevel_top

three_d_format.extrusion_color = "#FF008000"
three_d_format.extrusion_height = 6
three_d_format.contour_color = "#FF25353D"
three_d_format.contour_width = 1.5
three_d_format.depth = 3
three_d_format.material = "Plastic"

light_rig = LightRig()
light_rig.light_type = "Balanced"
light_rig.direction = "Top"
light_rig.x_rotation = 0
light_rig.y_rotation = 0
light_rig.z_rotation = 40
three_d_format.light_rig = light_rig

camera = Camera()
camera.camera_type = "PerspectiveContrastingRightFacing"
three_d_format.camera = camera
text_frame_format.three_d_format = three_d_format
dto.text_frame_format = text_frame_format

# Create the WordArt object and download the presentation.
slides_api.create_presentation(file_name)
slides_api.create_shape(file_name, slide_index, dto)
file_path = slides_api.download_file(file_name)
```

The WordArt object in the output presentation:

[image]

This is a paid product but you can make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing.

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.